# Erro ao tentar gerar apk assinado da minha aplicação

Tags: android

Olá, estou tentando gerar um apk assinado da minha aplicação e está aparecendo o seguinte erro;

**error: this class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)(com.tass.prova_legislacao_tp.BancoDados)[Instantiatable]**

```
package com.tass.prova_legislacao_tp;
```

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NOME = "legislac.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "provas_table";
public static final int VERSAO = 9;

public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_DATA = "DATA";
public static final String COL_HORA = "HORA";
public static final String COL_2 = "NOME";
public static final String COL_3 = "MATRICULA";
public static final String COL_4 = "FUNÇÃO";
public static final String COL_5 = "LOCAL";
public static final String COL_6 = "Q1";
public static final String COL_7 = "Q2";
public static final String COL_8 = "Q3";
public static final String COL_9 = "Q4";
public static final String COL_10 = "Q5";
public static final String COL_11 = "Q6";
public static final String COL_12 = "Q7";
public static final String COL_13 = "Q8";
public static final String COL_14 = "Q9";
public static final String COL_15 = "Q10";
public static final String COL_16 = "Q11";
public static final String COL_17 = "Q12";
public static final String COL_18 = "Q13";
public static final String COL_19 = "Q14";
public static final String COL_20 = "Q15";
public static final String COL_21 = "Q16";
public static final String COL_22 = "Q17";
public static final String COL_23 = "Q18";
public static final String COL_24 = "Q19";
public static final String COL_25 = "Q20";
public static final String COL_26 = "Q21";
public static final String COL_27 = "Q22";
public static final String COL_28 = "Q23";
public static final String COL_29 = "Q24";
public static final String COL_30 = "Q25";
public static final String COL_31 = "Q26";
public static final String COL_32 = "Q27";
public static final String COL_33 = "Q28";
public static final String COL_34 = "Q29";
public static final String COL_35 = "Q30";
public static final String COL_36 = "Q31";
public static final String COL_37 = "Q32";
public static final String COL_38 = "Q33";
public static final String COL_39 = "Q34";
public static final String COL_40 = "Q35";
public static final String COL_41 = "Q36";
public static final String COL_42 = "Q37";
public static final String COL_43 = "Q38";
public static final String COL_44 = "Q39";
public static final String COL_45 = "Q40";
public static final String COL_46 = "NOTA";



public BancoDados(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NOME, null, VERSAO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "DATA TEXT," +
            "HORA TEXT," +
            "NOME TEXT," +
            "MATRICULA TEXT," +
            "FUNÇÃO TEXT," +
            "LOCAL TEXT," +
            "Q1 TEXT," +
            "Q2 TEXT," +
            "Q3 TEXT," +
            "Q4 TEXT," +
            "Q5 TEXT," +
            "Q6 TEXT," +
            "Q7 TEXT," +
            "Q8 TEXT," +
            "Q9 TEXT," +
            "Q10 TEXT," +
            "Q11 TEXT," +
            "Q12 TEXT," +
            "Q13 TEXT," +
            "Q14 TEXT," +
            "Q15 TEXT," +
            "Q16 TEXT," +
            "Q17 TEXT," +
            "Q18 TEXT," +
            "Q19 TEXT," +
            "Q20 TEXT," +
            "Q21 TEXT," +
            "Q22 TEXT," +
            "Q23 TEXT," +
            "Q24 TEXT," +
            "Q25 TEXT," +
            "Q26 TEXT," +
            "Q27 TEXT," +
            "Q28 TEXT," +
            "Q29 TEXT," +
            "Q30 TEXT," +
            "Q31 TEXT," +
            "Q32 TEXT," +
            "Q33 TEXT," +
            "Q34 TEXT," +
            "Q35 TEXT," +
            "Q36 TEXT," +
            "Q37 TEXT," +
            "Q38 TEXT," +
            "Q39 TEXT," +
            "Q40 TEXT," +
            "NOTA TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
}


public boolean insertData(String data, String hora, String nome, String matricula, String função, String local, String questao01, String questao02,
                          String questao03, String questao04, String questao05, String questao06, String questao07, String questao08, String questao09,
                          String questao10, String questao11, String questao12, String questao13, String questao14, String questao15, String questao16,
                          String questao17, String questao18, String questao19, String questao20, String questao21, String questao22, String questao23,
                          String questao24, String questao25, String questao26, String questao27, String questao28, String questao29, String questao30,
                          String questao31, String questao32, String questao33, String questao34, String questao35, String questao36, String questao37,
                          String questao38, String questao39, String questao40, String notas) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_DATA, data);
    contentValues.put(COL_HORA, hora);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, nome);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, matricula);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, função);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, local);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, questao01);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, questao02);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, questao03);
    contentValues.put(COL_9, questao04);
    contentValues.put(COL_10, questao05);
    contentValues.put(COL_11, questao06);
    contentValues.put(COL_12, questao07);
    contentValues.put(COL_13, questao08);
    contentValues.put(COL_14, questao09);
    contentValues.put(COL_15, questao10);
    contentValues.put(COL_16, questao11);
    contentValues.put(COL_17, questao12);
    contentValues.put(COL_18, questao13);
    contentValues.put(COL_19, questao14);
    contentValues.put(COL_20, questao15);
    contentValues.put(COL_21, questao16);
    contentValues.put(COL_22, questao17);
    contentValues.put(COL_23, questao18);
    contentValues.put(COL_24, questao19);
    contentValues.put(COL_25, questao20);
    contentValues.put(COL_26, questao21);
    contentValues.put(COL_27, questao22);
    contentValues.put(COL_28, questao23);
    contentValues.put(COL_29, questao24);
    contentValues.put(COL_30, questao25);
    contentValues.put(COL_31, questao26);
    contentValues.put(COL_32, questao27);
    contentValues.put(COL_33, questao28);
    contentValues.put(COL_34, questao29);
    contentValues.put(COL_35, questao30);
    contentValues.put(COL_36, questao31);
    contentValues.put(COL_37, questao32);
    contentValues.put(COL_38, questao33);
    contentValues.put(COL_39, questao34);
    contentValues.put(COL_40, questao35);
    contentValues.put(COL_41, questao36);
    contentValues.put(COL_42, questao37);
    contentValues.put(COL_43, questao38);
    contentValues.put(COL_44, questao39);
    contentValues.put(COL_45, questao40);
    contentValues.put(COL_46, notas);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();

    return result != -1;
}
```

}

se puderam me dar uma luz de como resolver isso ficarei grato.

Comment: Este erro simplesmente diz que você deve fornecer um construtor público sem argumentos para sua classe. Não tenho certeza do porque este erro está ocorrendo sem olhar o seu projeto.

Comment: Creio que devo ter feito alguma coisa que não deveria, exclui este projeto e criei outro do início com as mesmas linhas e consegui assinar o apk sem problemas.